# How to split rows with condition? [pandas data frame]

Tags: pandas

I have example data frame like this:

```
id

0_123
0_1
1_45
2_567
3_1
```

How to get in reasonable quick way this:

```
id

0
0
1
2
3
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `df['id']=df['id'].str[0].astype(int)` **OR** `df['id']=df['id'].str.split('_',1).str[0].astype(int)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Thanks for a quick answer! It is working like I wanted.

Comment: If you wanted only the 1st character then use 1st method and If you wanted to get values on the left side of `'_'` then use 2nd method